# how to add image into listview's group?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a list with checkbox in each item and Image in group like CCleaner using listview control.
please help me.

I'm not have enough reputation to post image, so here the image location:
[image: http://lh5.ggpht.com/_S0f-AWxKVdM/TF_HPHDJp8I/AAAAAAAAM94/sEncyQ-GG2o/CCleaner-Enhancer%5B3%5D.png?imgmax=800]

Comment: If you want to do the same as the screenshot, you should use TreeView instead ListView.

Comment: I don't know why this question is marked as duplicate. Neither the other question nor the only answer here is about changing the image of a Windows Forms ListViewGroup (which is different from sub items as in the "duplicate", and also different from the only answer here which is about items), though both the title and the image suggest this. Google searches about this lead to this question, which is not answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to the designer, click on the ImageList component on the Component Tray, there will be a smart tag appear on the top-right corner of the ImageList.
2. Click the smart tag, and click "Choose Images" on the pane.
3. On the pop-up Image Collection Editor dialog, choose the images from the folder your want.
4. Click OK to finish adding images to the ImageList.
5. Click the ListView on the form, there will be a smart tag appear on the top-right corner.
6. Click the smart tag, you will find there're three ComboBoxes there, choose a ImageList from the list as you want.
7. Click the "Add items" option on the smart tag, a ListViewItem Collection Editor will appear, you can add items to the ListView, it's important here to set the ImageIndex or ImageKey property, or the image won't appear.
8. Click OK to finish item editing, now you'll find the images are displayed on the ListView.